# Boolean value is not changing

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I want to call a function from an other function in my background service to display a message.The problem is that i'm checking the boolean value and when i open my app it is initiated to **false** again so it runs the function again(i just want only one time).

Here is the code:

**OnCreate:**

```
 public void onCreate() {
    handler = new Handler();
    runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {          
            milestoneCheck();// THE FIRST FUNCTION
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, 10000);
        }
    };

    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 15000);

}
```

**first function**

```
public void milestoneCheck() {
    totalKm =(int) Float.parseFloat(TripsInfo.km.get(TripsInfo.userRank - 1));

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferencesInac = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    isSeen =sharedPreferencesInac.getBoolean("inactive", false);

    if (totalKm ==84 && !isSeen) {
        milestoneNotification(totalKm);
        isSeen = true;
    } else if (totalKm == 130 && isSeen) {
        milestoneNotification(totalKm);
        isSeen = false;
    } else if (totalKm == 200 && !isSeen) {
        milestoneNotification(totalKm);
    }

}
```

I also have the shared preferences in my mainactivity like this

```
 SharedPreferences sharedPreferencesIn = getSharedPreferences("inactivity", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editorIn = sharedPreferencesIn.edit();
    editorIn.putBoolean("inactive", false);
    editorIn.apply();

SharedPreferences sharedPreferencesInac = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        isSeen =sharedPreferencesInac.getBoolean("inactive", false);
```

And finally `isSeen` is a public static variable in my mainactivity!

So the problem is that isSeen is false in the beggining and then true but if i re-open the app is false again.

**UPDATE**

```
private void updateTrue() {

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferencesIn = getSharedPreferences("inactivity", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editorIn = sharedPreferencesIn.edit();
    editorIn.putBoolean("inactive", true);
    editorIn.apply();

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferencesInac = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    isSeen =sharedPreferencesInac.getBoolean("inactive", true);
}
```

**UPDATE V2**

I changed the function and i put it on Asynctask but i still got the same problem

```
protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {
        totalKm =(int) Float.parseFloat(TripsInfo.km.get(TripsInfo.userRank - 1));


        Log.d("test","before"+isSeen);

        if (totalKm ==84 && !isSeen ) {
            milestoneNotification(totalKm);
            updateTrue(true);
        } else if (totalKm == 130 && isSeen) {
            milestoneNotification(totalKm);

        } else if (totalKm == 200 ) {
            milestoneNotification(totalKm);

        }

        test=getSharedPreferences("inactivity",0);
        isSeen=test.getBoolean("inactive",false);
        Log.d("test","after"+isSeen);

        return null;
    }

 private void updateTrue(boolean value) {

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferencesIn = getSharedPreferences("inactivity",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editorIn = sharedPreferencesIn.edit();
    editorIn.putBoolean("inactive", value);
    editorIn.apply();

    test=getSharedPreferences("inactivity",0);
    isSeen=test.getBoolean("inactive",false);
    Log.d("test","function"+isSeen);
}
```

`updateTrue()` is **not** on AsyncTask

Comment: where are you setting the `boolean` value to `true` in `SharedPreferences`?

Comment: @Yousaf i don't.I thought that because i've made it static it gets the value true everywhere(even in the shared preferences)

Comment: no it doesn't do that. You have to set the value in `SharefPreferences` to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

you are setting `inactive` to false

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editorIn = sharedPreferencesIn.edit();
    editorIn.putBoolean("inactive", false);
    editorIn.apply();
```

If you want it to be true later on, set it to true

```
editorIn.putBoolean("inactive", true);
```